# Cant start my Spring Web Flow

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have an app that uses a Spring Web Flow. This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The definition of my flow in servlet-context.xml:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">

        <beans:property name="mappings">
        <beans:value>inicio.do=flowController</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="flowcontroller" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
    <beans:property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry"/>
    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices"> 
            <webflow:flow-location id="inicio" path="/WEB-INF/flujos/flujo.xml"/> 
    </webflow:flow-registry>   
    <webflow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" 
            view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator"/>
            <beans:bean id="viewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
            <beans:property name="viewResolvers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="viewResolver"/>
            </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
     <beans:bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
        <beans:property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"></beans:property>
     </beans:bean>
```

The flow is iniciated from another JSP, with a redirect. When the user clicks on the link that should lead to the flow, the "startflow.jsp" is called, and it has a redirect to the flow, this way:

```
<c:redirect url="inicio.do"></c:redirect>
```

As is now, I receive a 404 error page, saying that myapp/inicio.do is not available. What is what I am doing wrong? Can anybody help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dispatcher servlet appSerrvlet is mapped to ***.action** (see the .action extension in web.xml) where as in your SimpleUrlHandlerMapping you mapped to **inicio.do**.

This is how it works:

1)The server knows which servlet should handle the request depending on the request url and the servlet mapping in the web.xml.

2)DispatcherServlet receives the request and it checks the HandlerMapping and invokes the Controller associated with the request.

3)If FlowController is defined, dispactherServlet delegates request to it based on the handler mapping configuration.

But there is no servletmapping matching your request because there is no mapping to *.do.

So change your redirect to:

```
    <c:redirect url="/inicio.action"></c:redirect>
```

and mapping to:

```
    <beans:value>inicio.action=flowController</beans:value>
```

Comment: Yeah...I was thingking in doing that while Im facing other sort of problems in my app. You just confirmed my thinkings. It works, of course. Thank you a lot, Prasad.